# Ontology Computational Complexity

Tags: time-complexity, sparql, ontology

I wanted to know the computational complexity of ontologies. I am using the NIFSTD ontology and want to make a hierarchy based on some specific queries computation time (big O).

I have read that SPARQL itself is [Pspace-complete](http://repositorio.uchile.cl/bitstream/handle/2250/125956/Perez_Jorge.pdf?sequence=1). As you know, ontologies are usually based on RDF and are queried with the SPARQL.

I wanted the cost of searching for a concept in the ontology (select) and searching with a condition (where {...}).

In addition, is the computational complexity of opening and reading and ontology O(n) where n equals the size of the ontology file?

Thanks in Advance,
Aref

Comment: See also http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~ezolin/dl/

Comment: And especially [this](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~ezolin/dl/alc_to_shoiq.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Searching for a concept where the IRI is known is very fast - most APIs have indexes for these, so you can assume O(1) for this.

Searching with a `where` condition depends entirely on the condition. The more complex the condition, the higher the cost - the upper limit is the same as the worst case complexity you mentioned.

Another factor to be taken into account is whether you want to include any inference regime in your analysis or not; if so, then there's another source of unknown complexity there - OWL 2 DL inferencing has exponential worst case complexity, but what the actual difficulty of reasoning on a given ontology is depends on many factors, and it is not easy to predict. Still an open research question.

The cost of loading an ontology is roughly proportional to its size, although some axioms require more processing than others. Big variations between different APIs are to be expected; I would consider O(n) an acceptable approximation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems I cannot +1 your answer yet! :)